# C# System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown

Tags: c#

```
ulong rows, columns;
string answer;

Console.Write("How many rows: ");
answer = Console.ReadLine();
rows = ulong.TryParse(answer, out selectedRows);

if (rows == 0)
{ 
    rows= 1; 
}

Console.Write("How many columns: ");
answer = Console.ReadLine();
columns = ulong.TryParse(answer, out selectedRows);

if (columns == 0)
{ 
    columns = 1; 
}

byte [,] arrow1 = new byte[rows, columns];
row = 0;

// Initialization of the table is done here. 
for (byte i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
   gameRows[row, i] = Convert.ToByte(i);
}
```

If I choose rows = 220,000,000 and the columns = 10, this code throws a "System.OutOfMemoryException".

I'm using a 64-bit computer, Visual Studio 2022 and there are plenty of resources on the computer. I thought that my C# code should be 64 bit and not have this small memory limit.

But there is a limit in C# from what I understand.

The documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=net-6.0
writes:

> To override this default, you can use the  configuration file setting to enable arrays whose total size exceeds 2 GB.

How do I enable at runtime

```
gcallowverylargeobjects enabled="true" /gcallowverylargeobjects
```

/runtime

Where do I put this code?

I have tried to set it to 64 bit but this does not change anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjCwJ.png)

I have also read something about GCHandle.Alloc(Object, GCHandleType), but I cannot make any sense out of that one. I appreciate the help for a newbie in C# and Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem complete. Where does `row` come from? How is it incremented?

Comment: Why do you need 220 million rows in memory?

Comment: `GCHandle.Alloc` is for interoperating with native code. That is not what you are after.

Comment: I'm sorry about the typo. "row" should be rows.

Comment: Why do I want 220 million rows in memory? Because it's much faster to work with than disk, and I have plenty of memory on my computer. I even want more than 300 million rows.